# mysql sum two columns on the same values of another two columns

Tags: mysql, group-by, outer-join

I have a table like this:

[image]

I need to represent data in this way:

[image]

In the result, I can get the payment or receive of each currency on each date.
I tried group by + outer join, but failed.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want your results grouped by date you should use `GROUP BY` to group by date.

Then you can use `SUM` get the sum for each day.

But since you want different sums depending on the value of another column you have to use a `SUM` for every column you want and `CASE` inside in order to check the value of the other column and add the corresponding amount only if the column has the desired value.

Something like this should work.

You can also check the fiddle here
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05ab84/4

```
SELECT 
`TradeDate`,
SUM(CASE
    WHEN `BaseCCY`='EUR' THEN `BaseAmt`
    WHEN `TermCCY`='EUR' THEN `TermAmt`
    ELSE 0
    END) AS `EUR`,
SUM(CASE
    WHEN `BaseCCY`='USD' THEN `BaseAmt`
    WHEN `TermCCY`='USD' THEN `TermAmt`
    ELSE 0
    END) AS `USD`,
SUM(CASE
    WHEN `BaseCCY`='AUD' THEN `BaseAmt`
    WHEN `TermCCY`='AUD' THEN `TermAmt`
    ELSE 0
    END) AS `AUD`,
SUM(CASE
    WHEN `BaseCCY`='CNH' THEN `BaseAmt`
    WHEN `TermCCY`='CNH' THEN `TermAmt`
    ELSE 0
    END) AS `CNH`
FROM `test` GROUP BY `TradeDate`
```